# sencha touch iphone list arrow icon

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

I have an Sencha Touch 2 app with quite a few lists having `onItemDisclosure` set to `true`. They show a white arrow in a blue circle on both Android and iPhone, even though the iPhone is using `apple.css`.

Based on posts here and on the Sencha Forum, I've tried using

```
.x-list-disclosure {
    width: 10px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 0.6em;
    right:1em !important;
    -webkit-mask: none;
    -webkit-mask-box-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAANCAYAAACQN/8FAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ bWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAALRJREFUeNpi/P//P8OkSZMkGBgYtgNxfV5e3iYGLIBZSEhIGkjvB2Id IA4+efLkJXNz85voCpmgNBsSvRpogx+GQqBVT4G0LRDfx6cYbCIexd7oViMrvoOkeB1MMSPI18gA KGEPpA4gCYFs0WBCU6QCpJYiCYFscQPa9osJSZE61CRpJEW2QEV34G6EKtqLpOgRVNF95ADHpsgB WRHMxI9A/AWfIliAvwBJAvFudOuQAUCAAQDiG0runJxCpwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

But that's added a heavily scaled up iPhone arrow *underneath* the blue circle one.

How do I get rid of the blue one and make it look iPhone style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up fixing it manually:

```
.x-list-item .x-list-disclosure {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-mask: 0 0 url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAUCAYAAACEYr13AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAAAAAAAA+UO7fwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9wGBwQ7Dme80Q4AAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAAKBJREFUOMvtU7ENAyEQM0i0DJMMxggnNoCKhpWyBxVINBQUlyrRJwKeKF0Ul9bZ8vl0wO8ixshExGdzYkSGEDilBKUUeu+w1oqZgRyRrTUAQO8dSimskkydnXNcSgGAZRKx2s97zznnpYlcGRhjnsOzdeTGQa5Hk60SHyAiaK1vH5/xIOZa6wv/3oH4RjxcgYguu+JVAt4R46TArV/4A7gDIZZWTRQC+PUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=') no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#939393,#000000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#939393,#000000);
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1.2em;
    bottom: 30%;
}
```